# I have package X installed as a dependency. How can I discover which package pulls it in? ie Reverse Dependency

Tags: package

I tried to delete package X (in order to try an older built-in version). But when I restart emacs, it's automatically re-installed. `package-list-packages` lists it as a dependency so that behaviour seems reasonable, actually quite smart. The trouble is, I can't see what other package has created the dependency. I've tried visiting all the 'installed' and most of the 'dependency' packages in `(package|paradox)-list-packages` but X does not show up as a dependency.

I'd prefer to know how to find out this information, but X is org-plus-contrib-20181230 (I won't be uninstalling this permanently, it's just curiosity).

Comment: Use `M-x package-delete` to delete the package, and it will tell you what package depends on it.

Comment: Duh! Of course - you're right. That's (rpm -e <pkg>) what I used to do with RPM before I discovered --whatrequires. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All packages are in *~/.emacs.d/elpa*
Package dependencies are listed in files ending with "*-pkg.el*" in each package directory.

To find which packages require some package, find "*-pkg.el*"'s that contain that package's name.

### Using `M-x rgrep`:

Example: find all packages that require "*popup*" package.

<kbd>M-x rgrep</kbd>  prompts:

```
Search for:
```

Each dependency is in a list, so the name starts with a "**(**", then goes package name, one or more spaces, and a double quote(**"**) of a version string.
So, use basic regular expression to find a string in this format: `(popup "`

```
Search for: (popup \+"
```

```
Search for "(popup \+"" in files matching wildcard: *pkg.el
```

```
Base directory: /home/somename/.emacs.d/elpa/
```

### Result:

A **grep** buffer with links to all packages that depend on *popup*.

### UPD

In such situations just <kbd>`M-x rgrep`</kbd> everything.
I grepped all my Emacs installation for a "contrib" word. And there' a NEWS org file that logs all changes in new versions.
In version 7.9.2, about that "//orgmode.org/elpa/":

> You can now add the Org ELPA repository like this:
>
> (add-to-list 'package-archives '("org" . "https://orgmode.org/elpa/")
>   t)
>
> It contains both the =org-*.tar= package (the core Org distribution,
>   also available through https://elpa.gnu.org) and the =**org-plus***.tar=
>   package (**the extended Org distribution, with non-GNU packages from the
>   =contrib/= directory**.)

Comment: Works nicely - thanks for the code and the theory. In my case, popup is a dependency of dumb-jump. Unfortunately, org-plus-contrib is not a dependency of anything after all! So there is some other reason that it keeps getting installed. It's not a problem as I normally want it, it's just something else that I don't quite understand!!!

Comment: @wef Strange thing, I don't know where that org-plus-contrib comes from. It's not on MELPA, not on github.

Comment: Alex - it's from org-mode's own package repo by the look of it. My config (derived from ohai-emacs) includes these: `(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/") t) (add-to-list 'package-archives '("org" . "http://orgmode.org/elpa/") t)` - confusingly, the (built-in?) `gnu` repo has an 'org' package at version 20181230 and the `org-mode` repo has org-plus-contrib at the same version. I'm trying a virgin .emacs.d and building enough to install a few packages but I haven't been able to trigger the org-plus-contrib installation yet.

Answer (score 1):

Another reason a package might be listed as a dependency is because it is in `~/.emacs.d/elpa`, but not in `package-selected-packages`. One possible way to reach that state is install a newer version of a package, notice it, and delete one of them.